# Issue with running docker (network as local host) on fargate

Tags: docker, aws-fargate

I have a docker image which I run as follows:

```
docker run -d --net=host -p 8080:8080 <image_name>
```

I have a web server running on port 8080 and this along with --net=host ensures that I can run tests from a client on the docker host to this server.

Now, I am trying to deploy the same on an Amazon fargate server. I uploaded the docker image on the server and trying to do the above.
But it looks like this is not working.

What I did:

1. created a security group with port 8080 open on tcp for all IP's. I guess this should ensure all traffic including http should go through on this port. outbound traffic for this security group is open for all ip/ports. I have also opened icmp ports to ensure ping works.
2. I also configured the above port number 8080 for port forwarding in the container definition.
3. I also added a docker label as follows - key: --net, value: host.

I then create a task with this task definition. With the public IP that I get once this task starts, I try to access the webserver from Postman. However, it looks like it is not able to hit this server/port at all. I get a request timed out always.

I know the server is accessible cos I can ping it successfully. But for some reason, I get this error. 
I also checked the fargate logs and verified the server app is up and running.

some questions here:
1. Have I done something in opening the port number? Is this the right way to do it?

2. I did --net=host to ensure the docker container is available to the host to send requests. Is this even required on a fargate container? If so, what is the right way to do it? I did so by adding in docker labels.

Since the fargate container machine itself is up (can ping it) and the app is also up (from logs), I feel the above two points may address this issue.

Anything I may have missed. pls suggest.

Also, is there a way to see the exact docker command that gets executed when the fargate container is launced?

thanks in advance.

Comment: there is no host network in fargate, fargate use AWSvpc network mode. check logs of the application.

Comment: @Adiii, sure. thanks!

Comment: In addition, is this kind of port mapping even supported on fargate? I can ping the IP address but when I try to telnet to the IP port number, it fails. This tells me that the fargate container is definitely up and running since I can ping the machine itself. But it looks like the port mapping is not working at all. Is that soemthing that fargate even allows? Can we have a fargate container listening on any port number we want?

Comment: Please note that I am running my server on a non standard port (not the usual http port 80). The incoming requests will be http. Fargate only allows me to open tcp traffic on that port. I guess that automatically implies all tcp traffic including http on that port.